# Missing com.apple.application-identifier error for the generated distribution provisioning profile via Fastlane

Tags: testflight, provisioning-profile, fastlane, fastlane-gym

I can not upload a new build to AppStore because I get this error

when I tap `info` icon next to the distribution provisioning profile:

Entitlements: 6 included, 1 Missing

Missing com.apple.application-identifier

Although I already set an app identifier in info.plist

Is com.apple.application-identifier different than application-identifier?

also how can I add it in Entitlements?

[image]

Comment: I've reported the issue on `Fastlane` Github page.
https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/16681

Comment: Issue fixed in macOS Big Sur 11 Beta 2 Thanks Apple 

Answer (score 0):

**Quick fix**

Install the "Transporter" app from the MacOS app store.

OPEN Xcode 11.5 archive your project

Close Xcode 11.5 -> Command + Q

Open then Xcode 12 Beta

From Xcode's organizer, select your archive and press "Distribute App"

Instead of "Upload", select "Export" and proceed as usual.

Drop the exported .ipa into the transporter and press "Deliver".

And it Works!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with this:
(I exported to upload it to a firebase distribution)

1. Archive with Xcode 11.6
2. Quit Xcode 11.6
3. Open Xcode 12 beta2 (don't open the project)
4. Open Window -> Organizer
5. Distribute the App "normally"